# How is the current price on Uniswap v3 computed?

Tags: price, uniswapv3

My current understanding is that the current price is a state variable on a given pool (and it maps one to one to the current tick and the `sqrtPriceX96` variable. How is it set and updated though? It should work like a midpoint on traditional markets, but there are no bids and asks to talk about. I would be grateful for an example and/or a (code) reference. Thank you!